# Best way to track who has/hasn't received a post in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, random, schema

I am building an app that randomly selects a few people who have not received a post and sends it to them. But this requires keeping track of who has/hasn’t received the post. Is there any theory on how to do this in a scaleable way? What is the best way to track who has not received a post?

Answer (score 1):

you records for people in your database table.
add 2 more columns ..1) for bit flag and 2) for datetime sent.

-when your program sent post to one people change that sent flag  to 1 and update sent time.

-next time when you try to send again just check only whose sent flag is 0.

Comment: Whats the theory for adding a sent time?